# Extract first character from a string

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I've no knowledge regarding Windows batch programming syntax. I have a text file containing user IDs which I need to delete using curl command and for that I need to extract first character of every user ID and then pass to the curl command. I know the curl command which will require two variables:

1. 'UserID' - Read from the text file.
2. 'firstCharacter' - Extracting first character from the User ID.

Below is the code to fetch user IDs from users.txt file:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (users.txt) do call :processline %%a
pause
goto :eof
:processline
echo %*
goto :eof
:eof
```

Please help me with extracting the first character from the read User IDs.
Thanks.

Comment: Read [Variables: extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Comment: Cross posted: http://superuser.com/questions/1069816/dos-find-first-letter-from-a-string

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `cmd.exe` can do a limited amount of string parsing. JosefZ gave you a good place to start.

```
C:>echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
AMD64

C:>echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~0,1%
A
```

Answer (score 2):

In a batch / command file I was always needing the first x characters or a string and ended up with many functions all doing the same thing but different names, i.e. getFirstChar, getFirstTwoChars, etc.. - so decided to make a generic function where I could pass in the number of characters I needed:

```
::-- getFirstXChars
:getFirstXChars
    set sValIn=%1
    set /a iNo=%2
    set vWorkVal=%%sValIn:~0,%iNo%%%
    call:getFirstX %vWorkVal% vWorkVal2
    set %3=%vWorkVal2%

:getFirstX
    set %2=%~1
goto:eof
```

to use the syntax would be

```
set varToTrim=ABCDEFG

call:getFirstXChars %varToTrim% 2 varToTrimAfter

@echo 1 %varToTrim%
@echo 2 %varToTrimAfter%
pause
```

result from command file:

```
1 ABCDEFG
2 AB
```

Comment: Your function is **very** unstable, it fails in many cases, not only for all special characters in a string, but also for simple spaces in the string (or better, it can't handle strings with spaces). Better use call by reference instead of ByVal

Answer (score 2):

I just added to set variable "id" to be %%a, then I used substring notation to get the first character.
Substrings are processed by using `:~start,length` after the variable name and before the last `%` in the variable.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (output.txt) do set id=%%a & call :processline %%a
pause
goto :eof
:processline
echo %id:~0,1%
goto :eof
:eof
```